# Jordan curve and Conformal maps

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, conformal-geometry

Let $\mathbb D$ be the unitary open disk, $D$ a bounded domain(open and connected) with boundary a jordan curve and $f$ a conformal map from $\mathbb D$ to $D$, is it true that we can extend $f$ as an homeomorphism from $\overline{\mathbb D}$ to $\overline{D}$? and if it is true, does it hold for two bounded domains with boundary a jordan curve?

Answer (score 3):

Yes to the first question - this is a [theorem of Caratheodory.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(conformal_mapping))

And this implies a yes to the second question: If $f_j:\overline{\Bbb D}\to \overline D_j$ for $j=1,2$ are as above then $f_2\circ f_1^{-1}:\overline D_1\to\overline D_2$.

Comment: I can' t find this theorem in any book

Comment: @ClaudioDelfino There's what appears to be a fairly complete proof on the Wikipedia page. A weaker version of the result is in Rudin _Real and Complex Analysis_, Theorem 14.18; in the comments in section 14.20 he essentially states that the version above is true, no proof.